# Focus an element after it appears via ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript, focus, angular-ng-if

I have a button that, when clicked, is replaced with an input field and a confirmation button, then when input is finished it's replaced with the original button again.  When that happens, I want it to focus the original button after it appears (some users have requested better support for tab-navigation), but I can't seem to get it to do that consistently.  The best I've been able to do is this:

```html
// component.html
<button #durationButton *ngIf="!enteringDuration" (click)="enterDuration()">Enter Duration</button>
<ng-container *ngIf="enteringDuration">
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="duration" (keyup.enter)="setDuration()">
    <button (click)="setDuration()">&#10003;</button>
</ng-container>
```

```js
// component.ts
@ViewChild("durationButton") durationButton: ElementRef
duration: number
enteringDuration = false
shouldFocusDurationButton = false

ngAfterContentChecked () {
    if (this.shouldFocusDurationButton && this.durationButton) {
        this.shouldFocusDurationButton = false
        this.durationButton.nativeElement.focus()
    }
}

enterDuration () {
    this.enteringDuration = true
}
setDuration () {
    this.enteringDuration = false
    this.shouldFocusDurationButton = true
}
```

If I click or press enter on the confirmation button, focus moves to the original button as soon as it appears, but if I press enter in the input field the button appears but for some reason it doesn't gain focus until I move the mouse.  How do I make it work immediately for both?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `ViewChildren` and the `QueryList.changes` event to be notified when the button is added to or removed from the view. If the `QueryList` contains the button element, you can set the focus on it. See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frvpev) for a demo. Suggestion: you may want to do something similar to set the focus on the input field when it becomes visible.

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
...

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChildren("durationButton") durationButton: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  enteringDuration = false

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.setFocus(); // If the button is already present...
    this.durationButton.changes.subscribe(() => {
      this.setFocus();
    });
  }

  setFocus() {
    if (this.durationButton.length > 0) {
      this.durationButton.first.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }

  enterDuration() {
    this.enteringDuration = true
  }

  setDuration() {
    this.enteringDuration = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, with a few minor changes (I still had to use `shouldFocusDurationButton` to keep it from getting incorrectly focused when it appeared in a different context) this did exactly what I needed.  I was planning to use it for the input as well but had a problem where it was triggering the `keyup` event prematurely, but once I fixed that your solution worked there as well.

Comment: The stackblitz demo fails with on Windows 10 with Firefox 68.0.1, Edge 42.17134.1.0 and IE 11.829.17134.0 : the input does not get the focus. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @FlorianBeaufumé - I updated the code and stackblitz to account for cases where the button is already present when `ngAfterViewInit` is executed.

Comment: Sorry, I still get the same result, no focus on the input after I click the button.

Comment: Oh, but the question was not about setting the focus on the input; it was about setting the focus on the original button after pressing `Enter` in the input field. As mentioned in the answer, setting the focus on the input field was "left as an exercise"... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *ngIf and ViewChild don't play well together. I did a course on ViewChild and did an entire section just on handing the *ngIf.

One option is to use the hidden attribute instead of *ngIf.

Another option is to bind to a setter (similar to how you bound to a function):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I´ve been battling focusing issue my self for some time. A great solution in your case would be to create a custom directive:

```
export class AutoFocus implements OnInit {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

And place it on #durationButton and on Input. Since they both use *ngIf, as soon as an element is created it will be focused. Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-epxa8f?file=src/app/auto-focus.directive.ts).

PS. In my case `keyup.enter` was producing some unwanted behaviour, I would rather stick with `keydown.enter`.