# How to scroll to a new area on the page when a button is pressed

Tags: angular

My angular (6) code is set up so I have a section (We'll call this pageOne) on the bottom of the page that is tied to an `ngIf`. I want there to be a button on the top of the page, that when pressed displays `pageOne` by making it true, and then automatically scrolls to the bottom of the page.

I am able to get it to be true and display no problem, the only issue I'm having is getting it to scroll to the new section. Pressing the button once displays the content, and I have to press it again to get it to scroll down. I'm hoping to achieve this all on 1 click. I don't believe it's a time issue, I think it doesn't see the content on the page till the second click. Not sure though.

```
<button (click)='onDisplayContent()'>Start</button>
```

```
<div *ngIf="pageOne">
...
</div>
```

```
onDisplayContent() {
  this.pageOne = true;
  this.pageThree = true;

  this.scrollDown();
}

scrollDown() {
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53124292/1009922). It works with `*ngIf` as it does for `*ngFor`.

Comment: The whole breaks when I switch to ngFor

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. You can keep `*ngIf` and use the technique shown in [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53124292/1009922). It was posted for a question about `*ngFor` but it works with `*ngIf` as well.

Comment: You were clear, I just read wrong, sorry about that! My code editor isn't too happy with this.. https://imgur.com/l1kJBW5

Comment: [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567261/1009922) shows the classes that you need to import.

Comment: @Ryan Please take a look at this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658522/how-to-smooth-scroll-to-page-anchor-in-angular-4-without-plugins-properly/51400379#51400379

Comment: @Ryan or just relplace `*ngIf` with `[hidden]="!pageOne"`. this make sure that the element is present in the dom when you are initiating the scroll

Comment: Maybe putting a setTimeout could work

Comment: Hey @JoelJoseph doing the hidden trick is leaving me with the same issue, it has to be pressed twice to scroll