# Reference template variable is undefined in component when suing p3x-angular-compiler

Tags: angular, p3x-angular-compile

I'm using `p3x-angular-compiler` [plugin](https://github.com/patrikx3/angular-compile) and I have a reference variable in my html and I'm trying to get it in component.

HTML -

```
<div #scrollMe></div>
```

ts -

```
@ViewChild('scrollMe') private chatScrollContainer: ElementRef;
```

when i console `this.chatScrollContainer` in `ngOnInit` i get undefined.

Comment: If the `div` is inside an `*ngIf` conditional block, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567261/1009922).

Comment: I Tried that solution but still it ```this.chatScrollContainer``` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code from `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: still it's undefined

Comment: Maybe you have *ngIf in parent elements which is preventing it from rendering in html. I really can't make any better suggestion without seeing your code. If you're using angular 8, you can provide {static: false} as second parameter to @ViewChild() which will auto update reference on re renders of element.

Comment: It has to do something with ```p3x-angular-compile``` because if i use normal html template(not dynamic) it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old but the reason is that ***p3x-angular-compile*** creates a component with a context object inside which contains your variables.

You should prefix your template variables with 'context.':

```
{{context.foo}}
```